# Does an on-line flash buying guide exist with a feature search?

Tags: flash, online-shopping

I'm looking for something comparable to dpreview's [camera feature search](http://www.dpreview.com/products/search/cameras) and [lens feature search](http://www.dpreview.com/products/search/lenses).
There are plenty of buying guides on-line outlining to what parameters one should pay attention when buying a flash, but I didn't find a website that enables the user to search a large up to date database of flashes for certain features.
Does such a website exist?

Comment: It's not a search, and it only covers P-TTL flashes, but my [Pentax flash guide](http://pttl.mattdm.org/features:feature-tables) has a table comparing the features. It's mostly up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I use to search in this website: http://speedlights.net/compare-speedlight-specs/

It makes a large comparison on the specs of the brands.